# Как сделать темную полоску как а фото

Tags: html

Доброй ночи. Верстаю в учебных целях первый одностраничник. Как сделать внизу на картинке эту черную полоску с надписью?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `position: absolute;` ну или `display:flex` или `display:grid`... По разному можно, зависит от конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните изображение в блок и после изображения добвавьте блок с нужным текстом

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDyi1.jpg">
  <div class="text">Stack Overflow</div>
</div>
```